# Unable to debug St9bad_alloc error. Tried reducing the size of the data structure, error still persists

Tags: c++

I get a St9bad_alloc error which I'm unable to debug. I tried reducing the size of the data structure to eliminate the possibility that I might be running out of memory but that doesn't seem to be the case.

These are the relevant files:-

- gdb backtrace: http://pastebin.com/5hFhHXnL
- TraceCache.cc: http://pastebin.com/j8vK812j

I can't understand how, in the backtrace it jumps from TraceCache.cc:55 to TraceCache.cc:34 whereas in my code I can't see any such path.

Please let me know in case any other information is required.

Thanks

Comment: Do you build with optimizations turned on? Any chance of stack corruption?

Comment: No, I'm running this with debugging and optimizations off